# How can I make Firefox word-wrap text/plain files?

Tags: firefox

When I view [this IRC log](http://ci.mifos.org/irclogs/%23mifos/archive/2010/2010-01-04.log.gz) in Firefox, [long lines do not wrap](http://yfrog.com/izscreenshotmozillafirefop). But I wish they would! Anyone know how to make Firefox word-wrap text/plain files?

- this file is served as gzipped plain text; try `HEAD http://ci.mifos.org/irclogs/%23mifos/archive/2010/2010-01-04.log.gz` and you should see `Content-Type: text/plain`
- when the same resource is viewed in Google Chrome, [long lines wrap](http://yfrog.com/5ascreenshothttpcimifosorp)
- [this](http://doctype.com/get-text-files-wrap-when-displayed-browser-especially-firefox) might be a related question on doctype, but the "accepted answer" contains a broken link
- [this](http://ttcs.wordpress.com/2008/02/12/how-to-apply-word-wrap-to-text-files-viewed-in-mozilla-firefox/) didn't work for me (even the alternate version using `pre-wrap` as opposed to `-moz-pre-wrap` mentioned in a comment by user "Idran")
- using "View → Page Source", then toggling word wrap is a suitable workaround

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Toggle Word Wrap Firefox extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2351/) might work for you.

Comment: Adding an extension is not necessary. See answer below on making a simple change in `about:config`.

Answer (score 11):

FF 31. Open a new tab.

Enter `about:config` in the [Awesome Bar](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/awesome-bar-search-firefox-bookmarks-history-tabs).

Search for `view_source.wrap_long_lines` and set value to `true`.

Comment: @Twisty The `view_source.wrap_long_lines` preference predates version 2. That was why I deleted the reference to FF31.

Comment: @Paul Removing the original answerer's mention of FF 31 is too drastic of an edit ("clearly conflicts with author's intent"), even if the poster is wrong.  It would be better to either mention this information in a comment much as you've done, or construct the edit in a way that does not eliminate the original mention of FF 31.

Answer (score 4):

If you just need to wrap plaintext files, try Ctrl-U (then View -> Wrap Long Lines, if not already checked).  This solution is cleaner than an add-in with plaintext files, but sloppier with text embedded in html.

Comment: As of at least FF 51, this option is not available. See answer further down explaining how to configure in `about:config`.

Answer (score 4):

Go to the [Firefox User Profile](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Profiles).

This is for applying a style to all web pages you view.

Firefox User Profile Folder --> Chrome -- > **userContent.css** 
(If this file is not present, make a copy of userContent-example.css and rename it!

```
/*
 * This file can be used to apply a style to all web pages you view
 * Rules without !important are overruled by author rules if the
 * author sets any.  Rules with !important overrule author rules.
 */
```

This is for customizing Mozilla's user interface.

Firefox User Profile Folder --> Chrome -- > **userChrome.css** 
(If this file is not present, make a copy of userChrome-example.css and rename it!

```
/*
 * This file can be used to customize the look of Mozilla's user interface
 * You should consider using !important on rules which you want to
 * override default settings.
 */
```

Add to the bottom:

```
pre { white-space: pre-wrap !important; }
```

Save the file.]

Restart Firefox.  Works with Firefox 26.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is inspired by [@Travis's answer](https://superuser.com/a/284969/219873).

If you just need to wrap plain text files, then on the menu bar click `View` → `Page Style` → `Wrap Long Lines`.  This solution is cleaner than an add-on for plain text files, but sloppier with text embedded in HTML.

[image: Screenshot of Firefox menu]

Answer (score 1):

Here is an untested possibility, but the ideal solution if using `view-source:URL` with [View] [wrap long lines] enabled. This would be for the `text/plain` mime type to automatically use:

```
view-source: schema
```

This avoids the ctrl-u or menu [page source] click and reduces manual labour in an automated computing environment.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, Firefox 22 (the current target as of this writing) will introduce a new feature to allow wrapping text files directly in the browser. See [improved plain-text handling in Firefox](http://msujaws.wordpress.com/2013/03/08/improved-plain-text-handling-in-firefox/) for a preview, and [Firefox bug 253564](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=253564) for the gory details.