# How can I override preformatted text, forcing text wrap on a web page?

Tags: firefox, browser, opera, rendering

Many web pages with fixed formatting do not fit on my screen without scrolling left to right. I suspect that in some cases the web page attempts to determine my screen width and adapt to it, but fails because I use a 125% or 150% zoom factor.

Some time ago, Opera had a simple command to override all preformatted line widths and force text scrolling, but I haven't found a general solution since then. I looked at the question [How can I make Firefox word-wrap text/plain files?](https://superuser.com/questions/175604/how-can-i-make-firefox-word-wrap-text-plain-files) which had some answers for firefox, but both the extension suggested and the .css file seem to be out of date. I couldn't find any css files in my extension folder, so either they've changed it or I didn't understand where to look.

Ideally I would like a solution for Opera, but one for Firefox would be more helpful to the community and might be easier for someone to answer.

So, how can I force an unconditional text wrap to fit my screen in Firefox? Suggestions for any browser would be considered helpful, but an answer containing a solution for Firefox is preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it seems text wrap is nowhere to be found anymore, at least in Firefox. But it may not be Mozilla's fault entirely if a website forces their CSS on you, disregarding your FF Profile.

I am not so familiar with Opera but there is one suggestion, not ideal but a workaround for now: Select "View" and then 'Enter Reader View'.
It may not give you any fancy boxes etc. - but you could at least read the website's text and content on a small screen.

To switch back is very simple: just click the left top button to restore the page to normal.
I wish to have a better solution - hopefully, someone else may be able to know more.

Comment: I forgot to mention, if the website shows the option to select for mobile [the 3 or 5 lines] icon, you can switch temporarily to view in the mobile format.